# Number of ways of writing an integer as a sum of other integers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Fix a non-negative integer $m$. For any integer $A \geq 1$, use $P_m(A)$ to denote the number of ways of rewriting $A = A_1 + A_2 + \ldots A_k$, with $  1 \leq A_i \leq m$, for any $k \geq 1$.

I would like to find an upper bound for $P_m(A)$ as $A$ is large. Do you know some good reference for this estimate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence $P_m(0),P_m(1),P_m(2)\dots $ is known as the [$m$-step fibonacci sequence](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html).

The link contains various asymptotic results for the sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am trying to understand whether it is true that I can bound $P_m(n) \leq C^n$ where $C$ is a constant that does not depend on $m$.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the $A_i$ is not important, $P$ is the number of partitions of $A$ into parts not larger than $m$, see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html and https://oeis.org/A008284. It seems that for fixed $m$ these numbers are polynomials in the indeterminate $A$, which is made explicit for small $m$ in the sequences listed in the cross-references of the OEIS. So the leading coefficients of these polynomials would indeed provide estimates of the growth.