# Number of $n$-ples of integers summing to a given integer

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Fix a non-negative integer $m$. For any integer $A \geq 1$, use $P_m(A)$ to denote the number of ways of rewriting $A = A_1 + A_2 + \ldots A_m$, with $A_i$ non-negative integers (eventually $0$).

Is it true that $P_m(A) \leq C^A$ for any $A$, for some constant $C$?

What is it possible to see is that, by summing separately on the outcome of the first integer,
$$
P_m(A) = \sum_{j=0}^{A} P_{m-1}(A-j)
$$

Comment: What is $n$ here?  How does it relate to $k,m$? This is very similar to [your other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1871787/number-of-ways-of-writing-an-integer-as-a-sum-of-other-integers).  Why are you asking this separately?

Comment: Sorry I confused indices and now I corrected it. It is actually a different question, as $P_m(A)$ is defined differently. For this version, there is no Fibonacci description. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of ways of writing $A$ as a sum of $m$ non-negative integers is given by a ["stars and bars" argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) - it is equal to $\binom{A+m-1}{m-1}$.  Essentially, we think of $n$ stars representing the units we want to add up to get $A$, and we place $m-1$ bars separating the different summands.  There are $A + m-1$ symbols to place, and we have to choose $m-1$ of them to be bars, giving the formula.  For example, if $A = 11$ and $m = 5$,

$****||***|*|***$

would correspond to the sum $11 = 4 + 0 + 3 + 1 + 3$.

Hence $P_m(A) = \binom{A+m-1}{m-1}$.  If $m$ is fixed and $A$ grows, then this is a polynomial in $A$ of degree $m-1$.  In particular, using a standard bound on the binomial coefficients,
$$ P_m(A) = \binom{A + m - 1}{m-1} \le \left( \frac{(A+m-1)e}{m-1} \right)^{m-1}. $$

(This is valid as long as $m \ge 2$.  If $m = 1$ then $P_m(A) = 1$.)

However, there does need to be some dependence on $m$.  Note that we also have

$$ P_m(A) = \binom{A+m-1}{m-1} = \binom{A+m-1}{A} \ge \frac{m^A}{A!}, $$
so you cannot get a general upper bound that does not depend on $m$ at all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, by assuming $A_i \in \mathbb{N}$ I meant that $A_i$ might be $0$ as well.

Comment: I see that now.  Why require $k \le m$ then?  Why not have $A = A_1 + ... + A_m$, with any unnecessary terms being equal to $0$?

Comment: Yes that is maybe an easier way to write it. I modify the question then. Is there a way to generalize your argument to such a case?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit it now - you'll see the answer is on the same Wikipedia page.

Comment: I don't think that the formula that you wrote provides an uniform bound that does not depend on $m$... your upper bound goes to infinity as $m$ goes to infinity for any given $n$.

Comment: I very explicitly said that there cannot be a uniform bound that does not depend on $m$... any upper bound has to go to infinity with $m$, because the lower bound does.